# The partial derivatives of $F(x,y)=x^3y^4-\ln (x^2y)+e^{3x-6y}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

This is what I have so far, I am not really sure what I am doing is correct. Can anyone help with this?

> Given $F(x,y)=x^3y^4-\ln (x^2y)+e^{3x-6y}$
>
> Find $f_x,f_y,f_{xx},f_{xy},f_{yy}$
>
> $$P_x=3x^2y^4-\frac{2xy}{xy}+e^{x-6y}$$
> $$P_{xx}=6xy^4-2+e^{-6y}$$
> $$P_y=x^34y^3-\frac{x^2}{x^2}+e^{3x-6}$$
> $$P_x=x^312y^2-1+e^{3x}$$
> $$P_{xy}=\frac{6xy^4-2+e^{-6y}}{x^3-12y^2-1+e^{3x}}$$

Comment: First error: $\frac{d}{dx}e^{3x-6y}\neq e^{x-6y}$.  Use the chain rule.

Comment: Is that for Px? Would it be e^(3-6y)

Comment: It would be $3e^{3x-4y}$.

Comment: I edited, but for the future, [here's the LaTeX notation we use](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Would fxx=6xy^4-(2y/x^2y)+3e^x-6y?

Answer (score 1):

You did good. There are a few mistakes though

$$P_x = 3x^2y^4 - \frac{2}{x} + 3e^{3x-6y}$$

$$P_y = 4x^3y^3 - \frac{1}{y} - 6e^{3x-6y}$$

$$P_{xx} = 6xy^4 + \frac{2}{x^2} + 9e^{3x-6y}$$

Keep going for $P_{xy}$ and $P_{yy}$.

If you're differetiating w.r.t.  $x$, remember to treat $y$ as a constant. For instance, differetiating w.r.t. $x$ and also using the chain rule we have

$$\frac{\partial \ln (x^2y)}{\partial x} = \frac{2xy}{x^2y} = \frac{2}{x}$$

Comment: why are your answers different from the other post below? which one is right?

Comment: Pay attention to the simplifications, just as the example I gave.

Comment: @Ben: You can always cancel out common terms from numerator and denominator after and before differentiating.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19241/discussion-on-answer-by-aaron-maroja-the-partial-derivatives-of-fx-yx3y4).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to be worried about even when **partially** differentiating with respect to an independent variable.

**NOTE**: When you partially differentiate with respect to $x$, treat $y$ as constant.

I'll solve the first one for you as an example

$(x^3y^4)_x=3x^2y^4$

$(\ln(x^2y))_x={1\over x^2y}\cdot(x^2y)_x={2xy\over x^2y}$ **(You missed the square in the denominator)**

$(e^{3x-6y})_x=e^{3x-6y}\cdot (3x-6y)_x=3e^{3x-6y}$

Now club the three.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19240/discussion-on-answer-by-swapnil-tripathi-the-partial-derivatives-of-fx-yx3y).